# Error 310 after Drupal installation

Tags: redirection, installation

I've installed a fresh copy of Drupal 7.8 on an FTP server. For some reason, I am unable to run install.php, receiving the error:

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

The files have not been altered in any way.

What could be the problem?

Comment: check your `.htaccess`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't notice that Drupal 7 has compatibility problems while running on IIS and requires a complex (at least for me) configuration procedure to run correctly. 
I've reached that conclusion when I tried to install Drupal 6 on the same server, and it ran instantly.